# from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time import lib ImportError: No module named _constant_time

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-cryptography

I am basically deploying a flask app in app engine that uses pywebpush(https://github.com/web-push-libs/pywebpush). I followed the following tutorial to deploy(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env) But i am constantly getting the error in app engine while it works fine in local system.
The Error is: "from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time import lib
ImportError: No module named _constant_time".
Can Someone help me to over come this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That library is [not included](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27) in App Engine, so, you have to include it.

Follow the commands in [Copying a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library), in your case, with `pywebpush`, to do so.

EDIT: `pywebpush` depends on a library with C extensions, which [can not be used in Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27). To be able to use `pywebpush`, you will have to move to App Engine Flexible. I have followed [this example](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/hello-world), adding the `pywebpush` dependency and calling a function from it, and it worked both in local and deployed.

Comment: Hi, I checked again and I saw that the `pywebpush` library depends on a library with C extensions. Please, check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. That is the correct explanation to the problem.